# Refresh dependent div

Tags: php, html, background, resize

I have two web pages combined in one. One page is a navigation menu, the second is the actual content.

Both pages embeded in their own div and then those two divs included in another one(main).

The problem is that the menu might change its size from time to time(it has hover menu elements) and the second page has its background as image repeated till the bottom of the page. So when the menu's size increases, a bit of the second page stays blank.

How can I get the second part of the page to repaint the background, when the first page changes it height?

Any help of advice will be much appreciated.

UPDATE

Here is a part of the second page's css.

```
#servicesTextarea {min-height:229px !important; border-top:solid 3px #009ba7; background:#f2fafb url(../images/service_text_bk.gif) repeat-x right bottom;}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the div structure that I have

```
<div id="servicesStage">
<div id="servicesNav">
    <h2><a href="our_services.php">Our Services</a></h2>
            <ul>
        <li ><a href="software.php"><i>Fios</i> Software</a>
            <ul class=navigation>
                <li   ><a href="software_fios_enterprise.php"><i>Fios</i> Enterprise</a></li>
                <li   ><a href="software_fios_csa.php"><i>Fios</i> CSA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


        <li ><a href="managed_services.php">Managed Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="servicesTextarea">
    <div class="padding">
        <h4>Randon text</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><b><a href="software.php">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><b><a href="consulting.php">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned before the serviceNav div contains a navigation menu that might increase its size, and I want the background of the servicesTextarea to get updated.

Here is the picture of what I'm trying to avoid 
[image]

Comment: On your div css, you might do like this "backgroud: url('www.image.com/image.jpg') repeat;"

Comment: I'm already doing that (see the update) 

The problem is that when when the first (left) part of the page gets bigger, the second (right) part of the page does not get its background refreshed.

Comment: Why would it's background be refreshed, your not specifying it to?
Also it's only repeating along the x axis, did you mean for it to be like that?

Comment: you need to make sure the second div also grows when the first one does - you can either do this through javascript or the use of css display table and table-cell.  Can you provide the html structure for the divs too

Comment: The thing is that the second div also grows, as they both are in the same parent div. Although I don't know how to get the background to refresh

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the actual background of the second page stays blank? Slightly unclear in your question but if so then use:

```
background: url('/path/to/image.jpg') repeat;
```

With the repeat part being the crucial change. All this will do is make the background image repeat to fill the div or page, even when the div is resized.

Hope that helps

Comment: As you can see on the picture, when the menu div gets bigger, the content div does not get it's background repainted. That's what I want to achieve. I already have the "repeat" setting specified.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can get a clean solution with pure CSS, if not putting the background in another wrapper outside that contain the `servicesTextArea` and `servicesNav` containers.

However, is a dead simple in javascript.

[This might be helpfull.](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)